# iOS 8 modify "asset Remove Alert" with Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, title, alerts

In iOS 8 you're allowed to easily delete assets from Camera Roll.
I already use this function in my App but I wan't to change the text of the alert, which is visible.

Image:

[image]

Now I want to change the title of the alert.
Did everybody know, what I have to do that i can change the title of the alert?

I use Objective-C in Xcode.

Comment: Your client does not have permission to get URL /TJd0-gjBQbvaOJJKgfjdWxwR2KZ_gw-1t4EH31To1MIv1yBQSfl6so2qxG6158Hgsh5HxKkwmKVzzxc=w2536-h1169 from this server.

Comment: now the image does work